# Coursework - Creating a Match-3 "Candy Crush" Game in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, ansi-escape

I'm having a little bit of trouble on an assignment and am looking for some advice. I'm supposed to create a "game" that is similar to Candy Crush or Bejeweled. The assignment takes in a .txt file that contains a matrix of values from 1-5 and then assigns each value to a spot in a [10][10] array. Then an Escape Code function prints out colored pixels in place of the number values for each spot, creating a "game board" looking output. Finally, the program is supposed to look for any matches of 3 same-colored pixels and replace them with a white pixel and "XX". Then the program prints the corrected game board with the matches X'd out.

I have it mostly coded, but I've encountered a couple of issues...

1.) I am supposed to label the columns and rows 0-9, and while I have no problem coding the labels for the columns using printf( ), when I try to print the row labels I get a random string of numbers.

2.) I replaced the matches with white pixels by reassigning the value in the array to 7, for which the ANSI Escape Code is white. However, I'm unsure about how to print the "XX" in the same spot.

I wish I could post some pictures as an example but I don't have enough "reputation" on this site as a new account. I've included my code so far below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printEscapeCode(int c);

int main(void)
{
    /* Declare an image array to be gameboard */
    int gameboard[10][10];

    /* Declare variables and load in how many rows and columns */
    int Nrows;
    int Ncols;

    scanf("%d %d",&Nrows, &Ncols);

    /* Load in candy values for each row */
    int row, col;
    for(row = 0; row < Nrows; row++)
    {
            /* Load in candy values for each column */
            for(col = 0; col < Ncols; col++)
            {
                   /* Declare variable to hold value */
                    int x;
                    scanf("%d",&x);
                   /* Tell where to store candy value */
                    gameboard[row][col] = x;
            }
    }
    /* Calls function to print candy colors for each row */
    printf("  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n");
    for(row = 0; row < Nrows; row++)
    {
            printf("0 ");
            /* Calls function to print candy colors for each column */
            for(col = 0; col < Ncols; col++)
            {
                    /* If statement to look for three matching candies */
                    if(gameboard[row][col] == gameboard[row+1][col] && gameboard[row+1][col] ==  gameboard[row+2][col])
                    {
                            /* Sets matching candies to display white */
                            gameboard[row][col] = 7;
                            gameboard[row+1][col] = 7;
                            gameboard[row+2][col] = 7;
                    }
                    if(gameboard[row][col] == gameboard[row][col+1] && gameboard[row][col+1] == gameboard[row][col+2])
                    {
                            gameboard[row][col] = 7;
                            gameboard[row][col+1] = 7;
                            gameboard[row][col+2] = 7;
                    }
                    printEscapeCode(gameboard[row][col]);
            }
            printEscapeCode(7);
            printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Function that prints candy colors */
void printEscapeCode(int c){
    printf("\x1b[4%dm  ",c);

}
```

Comment: this is more for code review site?

Comment: @JoeBlow Code Review is only for _working_ code.

Comment: One of your problems is that `Nrows` and `Ncols` isn't initialized to proper values. Since those variables are on the stack, the `for` loops (`row < Nrows` and `col < Ncols`) will not run up to 10 (your board size) but up to some random value. Another one is that you index `gameboard[row+1][col]` and `gameboard[row][col+1]` but the `for` loop attempts to take the index up to and including the last element (so when `row` is max, `row+1` overruns). Also here, `Nrows` and `Ncols` is undefined. Then you have a `printf("0 ")` instead of printing the row number. I didn't analyze further...

Comment: @Karel Kubat When the program runs, it uses scanf to read in the array values as well as Nrows and Ncols, so I think they are initialized through that? In this case, Nrows and Ncols will always be 10 10 in the txt file. printf ("0 ") was added so that I would remember where to put the actual code once I figured it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Joe Blow, I'm confused as to why you think my question is not suitable for this site?

Comment: @AmandaPhelps, you're right, `Nrows` and `Ncols` is initialized in `scanf()`. But then your board is always limited to 10x10, so practically you can't exceed that size. Still beware of the +1 overrun.